# jquery slide effect, hide one div and show another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ggfA6/7/) setup demonstrating my problem, I'm sure that it's a simple fix.

I am trying to slide out the blue div to the left, while sliding in the red div from the right, at the same time. The sliding animations are working how I want them to, however when the red div is sliding in it appears below the blue div. How can I get it to be positioned to the right of the blue div instead of appearing beneath it during the animation?

code:

```
$("#slide2").on('click', function(){
    $( "#blueDiv" ).effect( "slide", hideoptions, 1000);
    $( "#redDiv" ).effect( "slide", showoptions, 1000);                
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use position: absolute to take them out of the flow and place them beside each other:

```
div > div
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you want to make it more specific to this div, you can use a specific selector:

```
#contentWrapper div
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggfA6/8/)

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/ggfA6/12

```
position: absolute
```

Both elements need to be absolutely positioned so that they don't occupy space in the flow.